# How to read a .pages file from iWork on a PC

Tags: documents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read .pages from a flash drive on a PC](https://superuser.com/questions/236589/how-to-read-pages-from-a-flash-drive-on-a-pc)

I made a document on my Macbook Pro in [Pages](http://www.apple.com/iwork/pages/) (its extension is .pages). Is there a Windows program that can read this document?

Comment: What kind of document are they on your MacBook

Comment: The document was created with iWork.

Comment: Next time you ask questions, try to include more information than leaving out.

Comment: @~quack sorry, I edited it the same time as you.

Answer (score 3):

You can just open up the .pages file using 7zip (or some such zip compatible archiving util) and extract the included PDF if you need instant access.

Reference: http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/11/01/iwork-files-are-really-just-zip-files-and-contain-pdf-previews/

But going forward, as suggested, change your default save file-type for ease and cross-platform editability.

Answer (score 1):

Open it again in Pages and save it as a **doc** or **docx** file type. This ensures it's readable from both Pages and Word. The downside to this is that you might lose some formatting (I'm not sure if that will happen, but it is a possibility).

Answer (score 1):

The version of pages that I am using has a "share" option near the top of the screen towards the right. Select that, and then select "send via mail" and you can choose to send the file in PDF or Word format instead of as a `.pages` file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mac Forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=419945):

> Pages files (actually packages) can only be read on a Mac with Pages. To send the files to a Windows user, export as Word or PDF.