# How to read .pages from a flash drive on a PC

Tags: windows, software-rec, iwork-pages

I need to read on my PC laptop some `.pages` files on a flash drive; how do I do this since they were not saved as a doc or pdf file (and I have no Mac available to change them)?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to extract (unzip) the `.pages` package and view the preview PDF inside (if it was saved with a preview). This process is documented [here](http://pagesfaq.blogspot.com/2007/10/is-there-pages-viewer-for-windows.html).

Alternatively, there is a [Pages to `.txt` converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pagesconvert/) available for free on SourceForge. This won't preserve the formatting or layout of the document, or any styles or images however.